# How to give a border as a background in css without using image and without adding anything to mark-up?

Tags: html, css

For example here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/5Wqn4/1/

I want to take `<h1>` over red area. How to make is possible without using image **and another added more element**.

using `border` is not necessary I just want background like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any extra markup, there's a couple of things you could do.

**Apply a negative top margin on the h1:**

```
h1{margin-top:-150px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Wqn4/2/

**Position the h1 absolutely:**

```
h1{
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 left: 50px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Wqn4/3/

**Without your body border:**

Without using the border you've added to the body you can simply style the h1 as you require:

```
body {background:yellow;margin:0;padding:0;}

h1{
    background-color:red;
    margin:0;
    height:150px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Wqn4/5/

**UPDATE**

Further to your comments below, here's a sample that probably matches more what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/SbGDQ/

Comment: Can we make a background like this with any other method in CSS instead using border and giving positioning to `<h1>`?

Comment: Look at my addition. You can simply style the h1 and remove the border (and padding) from the body

Comment: +1 for your efforts but Actually I have other elements too other then `H1` so giving the red to whole `h1` will not work for me. The main thing I want is the background of Body. Is there any other ways in CSS or HTML5 Gradient, canvas etc to get the background like this?

Comment: Ideally you just need a container element for the header.

Comment: Why I can't give this read background to `#header` because my header will be fixed width and centered. but the red border of `body` is fluid. and I can achieve this with an image but I just want to know if it's possible to make background like this without image

Comment: So my guess then is that you have a container? #wrapper or #container etc. You could use the border and simply put the negative margin on the container pulling your header up over the border. I'll make a sample.

Comment: Great - You solved the problem. I hope it will work in all browser including iPad

Comment: I would recommend giving the h1 tag a class though when applying this CSS to it. Save applying it globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS rule:

```
h1 {
 border-top: 20px solid red;
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 body {background: yellow;padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
 h1{background: red;line-height: 10em;margin: 0px;}
```